# Issue with Python Loop handling

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary that looks something like this :

```
data = {'student': {'gradeone': {'subject1': {'result': {'marks': '91', 'remarks': 'pass'}, 'id': 'RA110'}, 'studious': Yes, 'Defaulter': [], 'overall': 'EXCELLENT'}}
```

For this I wrote the following code which checks for "overall" key and if it is set to "Excellent" function returns TRUE :

```
if(data and 'student' in data and
   'gradeone' in data['student'] and
   'overall' in data['student']['gradeone']):
    if(data['student']['gradeone']['overall'] == 'EXCELLENT'):
        return True
    return False
return False
```

But if the data is something like this :

```
data = {'student' : None }
```

My function instead of returning False returns an error saying "None Type Object is not iterable"

Can you help modify the function appropriately so that when the "student" key is none, the function returns false appropriately without returning the aforementioned error ? Should a try-catch be used?

Comment: Your indentation is poor (actually, it is wrong), which conceals the fact that you have 3 return statements for only 2 if statements. I do not understand your purpose well enough to decide which return statement, if any, is superfluous. Clean up your code and see if that makes it easier to find your error.

Comment: You should show the whole function so that we can understand where the return statements belong.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do something like:

```
def is_excellent(data):
    try:
        return data['student']['gradeone']['overall'] == 'EXCELLENT'
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return False
```

Comment: `except (KeyError, TypeError):` will actually work in case one of the entries exist but contains None instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`'gradeone' in data['student']` is causing the problem: if `data['student']` is `None`, the operator `in` is not applicable.